# Disable screen scaling in Xvesa?

Tags: linux, resolution, xvesa

Is it possible to disable the X screen from stretching to fill the monitor? For instance, if Xvesa is configured to display 800x600, can I have that 800x600 box centered in the middle of the screen with black surrounding it, rather than stretched to fit a possible different aspect ratio?

Comment: This almost completely depends on your display.

Comment: Displays have an input scaler in them (except for the very high-end ones because it adds latency) to fake non-native modes, as do most graphics cards. However, I'm pretty sure there's a signal that can disable that. I know I had some software waaay back in the DOS days that could do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to pull this off. I did found that each graphics card has its own way of disabling the video card output scaler and there are different hacks to pull that off (for instance, the ancient [NVSC](http://rayer.ic.cz/programm/programe.htm#NVSC) from the dos days for nVidia cards). I could not find any documented or undocumented way of doing this with ATi cards.

The display's scaler is, as far as I can tell, automatically disabled if the video card scaler is as well.